# What's the overhead of using built-in python functions like zip() and join() on the performance of my function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, big-o

Below I have provided the function to calculate the LCF (longest common prefix). I want to know the Big O time-complexity and space complexity. Can I say it is `O(n)`? Or do `zip()` and `join()` affect the time-complexity? I am wondering the space complexity is `O(1)`. Please correct me if I am wrong. The input to the function is a list containing strings e.g., `["flower","flow","flight"]`.

```
def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs):

    res = []

    for x in zip(*strs):
        if len(set(x)) == 1:
            res.append(x[0])
        else:
            break

    return "".join(res)
```

Comment: Just so you know, there is a stdlib [`commonprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) function avail for the same.

Comment: Please *always* use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions

Answer (score 3):

Iterating to get a single tuple value from `zip(*strs)` takes `O(len(strs))` time and space. That's just the time it takes to allocate and fill a tuple of that length.

Iterating to consume the whole iterator takes `O(len(strs) * min(len(s) for s in strs))` time, but shouldn't take any additional space over a single iteration.

Your iteration code is a bit trickier, because you may stop iterating early, when you find the first place within your strings where some characters don't match. In the worst case, all the strings are identical (up to the length of the shortest one) and so you'd use the time complexity above. And in the best case there is no common prefix, so you can use the single-value iteration as your best case.

But there's no good way to describe "average case" performance because it depends a lot on the distributions of the different inputs. If your inputs were random strings, you could do some statistics and predict an average number of iterations, but if your input strings are words, or even more likely, specific words *expected to have common prefixes*, then it's very likely that all bets are off.

Perhaps the best way to describe that part of the function's performance is actually in terms of its own output. It takes `O(len(strs) * len(self.longestCommonPrefix(strs))` time to run.

As for `str.join`, running `"".join(res)` if we know nothing about `res` takes `O(len(res) + len("".join(res)))` for both time and space. Because your code only joins individual characters, the two lengths are going to be the same, so we can say that the join in your function takes `O(len(self.longestCommonPrefix(strs)))` time and space.

Putting things together, we can see that the main loop takes a multiple of the time taken by the `join` call, so we can ignore the latter and say that the function's time complexity is just `O(len(strs) * len(self.longestCommonPrefix(strs))`. However, the memory usage complexities for the two parts are independent and we can't easily predict if the number of strings or the length of the output will grow faster. So we need to combine them and say that you need `O(len(strs) + len(self.longestCommonPrefix(strs)))` space.

Answer (score 1):

Time:

Your code is `O(n * m)`, where `n` is the lenght of the list and `m` is the lenght of the biggest string in the list.

- `zip()` is O(1) in python 3.x. The function allocates a special iterable (called the zip object), and assigns the parameter array to an internal field. In case of `zip(*x)` (pointed from @juanpa.arrivillaga), it builds a tuple, so it is `O(n)`. As a result, you will get an `O(n)` because you iterate over the list (tuple) plus the `zip(*x)` call staying at the end with `O(n)`.
- `join()` is O(n). Where `n` is the total length of the input.
- `set()` is O(m). Where `m` is the total lenght of the word.

Space:

- It is `O(n)`, because in the worst scenario, `res` will need to append `x[0]` `n` times.

Comment: `zip(x)` is constant time, but `zip(*x)` is linear on the size of x, it actually builds a tuple. Of course, that doesn't change the rest of the analysis

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks fot the comment. I added those infos to the answer.

Comment: Your statement that `m` is the length of the longest word is entirely wrong. The sets are being built from `x` values that come from `zip`, so they're all tuples of the same length, `len(strs)`. Furthermore, the longest word never matters, only the shortest word (in the worst case). `zip` ends when the first of its iterable arguments is exhausted, so e.g. with `['f', 'foo', 'foobar']`, only the length of `'f'` matters.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for clarifying on this. I agree that m should be the shortest word instead of longest as mentioned by j3r3mias.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. A used longest because zip(*x) check all the strings in the list before use the lenght of the shortest one.